# JSF ajax rerender component when property changes

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

Can I re-render some component when property in the bean is changed. For example if I have ApplicationScoped bean and one of it's properties is List, I wan every time when some user add element in the list, everybody else to see the change, without to submit the form. Something like chat room. When someone add message to the collection, it has to be rendered immediately to the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use server-side push. Watch [this](http://www.slideshare.net/mwessendorf/doing-serverside-push-with-jsf) to know how it can be done with Oracle ADF Faces.
And [this](http://www.icefaces.org/main/ajax-java/ajaxpush.iface) with ICEfaces push component

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`<a4j:push>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/push.jsf?c=push) or [`<a4j:poll>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/poll.jsf?c=poll) to refresh partial pages on a timer.